# How to access custom method attributes from ProxyGenerationHook in Castle.DynamicProxy

Tags: c#, .net, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm implementing **Interceptor** mechanism in .NET with Castle.DynamicProxy (Castle.Core 4.4.0). I'm following this tutorial for selecting which method to intercept: https://kozmic.net/2009/01/17/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-iii-selecting-which-methods-to/

It was given an example in this article about "selecting which methods to intercept":

```
public class FreezableProxyGenerationHook:IProxyGenerationHook
{
    public bool ShouldInterceptMethod(Type type, MethodInfo memberInfo)
    {
        return !memberInfo.Name.StartsWith("get_", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
    //implementing other methods... 
}
```

According to this article, I implemented the `ShouldInterceptMethod` like below but i can not access the method's custom attributes.

```
public class ProductServiceProxyGenerationHook : IProxyGenerationHook
{
    public void MethodsInspected()
    {
    }
    public void NonProxyableMemberNotification(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
    }

    public bool ShouldInterceptMethod(Type type, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        //return methodInfo.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(UseInterceptorAttribute));
        return methodInfo.CustomAttributes.Count() > 0;
    }
}
```

This is the method that i want to intercept:

```
[UseInterceptor]
public Product AOP_Get(string serialNumber)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();      
}
```

This is my custom attribute:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class UseInterceptorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public UseInterceptorAttribute()
    {
    }
}
```

When `ShouldInterceptMethod` invoked for `AOP_Get` method, there aren't any custom attributes on local variable `methodInfo`. As a result `ShouldInterceptMethod` returns `false`. But when i check from the `AOP_Get` method body, i can access custom attribute like below:
[image]

How can i access custom attributes in `ShouldInterceptMethod` method?

Comment: Can you upload a minimal example to github so I can fiddle around with it?

Comment: @Simon: I uploaded the minimal example to GitHub: [link](https://github.com/tolgacakir/AOP_Example)

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255182/autofac-method-level-interception-with-castle-dynamicproxy-in-net-core-2) is usable but still we are intercepting all of the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using `UseInterceptorAttribute` in the **interface** methods. Because the interceptor is enabling for interface:

```
//autofac
var proxyGenerationOptions = new ProxyGenerationOptions(new ProductServiceProxyGenerationHook());

builder.RegisterType<ProductService>()
                .As<IProductService>()
                .EnableInterfaceInterceptors(proxyGenerationOptions)
                .InterceptedBy(typeof(LoggingInterceptor));
```

The solution:

```
public interface IProductService
{
    Product Get(string productNumber, string serialNumber);

    bool Create(string productNumber, string serialNumber);

    [UseInterceptor]
    Product AOP_Get(string productNumber, string serialNumber);

}
```

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{ 
    public Product AOP_Get(string productNumber, string serialNumber)
    {
        var m = GetType().GetMethod("AOP_Get");
        return null;
    }

    public bool Create(string productNumber, string serialNumber)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public Product Get(string productNumber, string serialNumber)
    {
        return new Product
        {
            Id = 5,
            ProductNumber = "testPN",
            SerialNumber = "testSN"
        };
    }
}
```

```
    public class ProductServiceProxyGenerationHook : IProxyGenerationHook
    {
        public void MethodsInspected()
        {
        }

        public void NonProxyableMemberNotification(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo)
        {
        }

        public bool ShouldInterceptMethod(Type type, MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            return methodInfo
                .CustomAttributes
                .Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(UseInterceptorAttribute));
        }
    }
}
```